# Sending mail with Google Apps Script and spam

Tags: email, google-apps-script, spam

I'm assisting a class of about 60 students where I developed a little script to email them their exam grades previously loaded in a GSheet. I'm worried that sending 60 mails in a matter of a few seconds may be considered as SPAM. Should i be worried about this? And if so, what measures could i implement? Adding a sleep() before every send email command?

Thanks!

Comment: Note the quota limits on email: https://script.google.com/macros/dashboard/quota

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the volume of emails has no effect on the decision of whether a mail is spam or not. That decision is made on the client side and the client has no way of knowing the volume of emails being sent.

I use this same method to send a PDF grade report to 1200 students and have never had a problem.

Comment: 1200? Wow, you are hardcore. Thanks!

Comment: Ha, not that hardcore but I use it to Email a grade report 4 times per year to every student in the school, it's extremely efficient and has saved a considerable amount of paper and other resources. A few other things to consider - if a user is receiving more than 60 emails per min then the email won't be delivered. G Suite for Edu is limited to 1500 Email per 24 Hrs.